# Fast branchless max for unsigned integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, bit-manipulation

I found a trick from the [AGGREGATE Magic](http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/) for fast computing max values. The only problem that this is for integers, and however I have tried some things, have no idea how to make a version for unsigned integers.

```
inline int32_t max(int32_t a, int32_t b)
{ 
    return a - ((a-b) & (a-b)>>31);
}
```

Any advice?

**EDIT**

**Do not use this, because as others stated it produces undefined behavior. For any modern architecture the compiler will able to emit a branchless conditional move instruction from `return (a > b) ? a : b`, that will be faster than the function in question.**

Comment: Wait, are you really sure this is faster than `return a > b ? a : b`?

Comment: This function is pretty much useless. Use `std::max`.

Comment: Yeah, on modern CPUs with pipeline, branches are slow. I have measured, this version as much fast as the SSE version, if not faster.

Comment: My advice is not to assume that the compiler writers don't know such tricks themselves.

Comment: No bueno: Right shifts of negative integers are implementation defined (§5.8p3).

Comment: Sorry, but the question isn't about "How to do this in another way". I made some tests and this trick beats std::max with O3 otimization level on GCC 4.7. I see no reason for the downvote.

Comment: What's `max(-2,INT_MAX)`? [Your program says it's -2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=9efb40503208b4347a4d50a5accc4524-c944ac6b0eed3bfc48b1f78a894f6965).

Comment: On x86 GCC uses branchless conditional move instruction for this: [see here](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#{%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A{%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22intel%22%3Atrue%2C%22colouriseAsm%22%3Atrue}%2C%22compilers%22%3A[{%22source%22%3A%22%23include%20%3Calgorithm%3E\nint%20max%28int%20x%2C%20int%20y%29%20{\n%20%20return%20std%3A%3Amax%28x%2Cy%29%3B\n}\n%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fg%2B%2B-4.7%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O2%20-m32%20-march%3Dnative%22}]}). I'll be surprised if this is really slower than your code.

Comment: @plasmacel: On modern CPUs with conditional assignment, there are no branches here, slow or otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I highly doubt that this code is faster than `std::max` on a modern compiler.

Comment: If it was faster GCC would just generate it like that. GCC can easily recognize the max idiom and convert it to whatever it likes.

Comment: @plasmacel When code with undefined behavior exhibits different behavior in different situations, it's not weird - it's basically expected.

Comment: If you're OK with assuming that the `uint32_t`'s in the unsigned version will always be <= INT_MAX, then you can use exactly the same trick but with a cast to make sure the shift is signed. That's equally undefined as this code, which in this specific cases means it'll usually work anyway..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What does this code do? It takes the value of a and the difference `a - b`. Of course, `a - (a - b)` is `b`. And `(a - b) >> 31` simply creates a mask of ones iff `a - b` is negative.

This code is incorrect, iff you get an overflow on the subtraction. That, however is the same story as for unsigned integers. So iff you are content with the fact, that your code is not correct for the entire value range, you can simply ignore unsignedness and use this:

```
inline uint32_t umax(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    return (uint32_t)max((int32_t)a, (int32_t)b);
}
```